# How to change a ScrollContainer's scrollbar thickness in Godot 4.x

Tags: user-interface, scrollbar, godot4

In Godot 4.x, how do you change the ScrollContainer's scrollbar thickness?

Answer (score 1):

Even though the answer from Dustin_00 allows to increase the bar width beyond the default, which is 8 pixels, it will not help when trying to decrease the value to less than 8. The only way I was able to reduce the scrollbar width was changing the 'size.x' property from code to 0.125, this gave me a bar with one pixel width which is what I wanted. But since this scales the bar it may not produce the desired visual result without other work arounds

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm old, can't see small things, and shrinking the scrollbar was very not on my radar, thanks for adding your insight!

Answer (score 0):

New tag needed [scrollcontainer], *sigh*

This shows how to change thickness of the VScrollbar to 55.

This requires 2 changes, 1) adjust the container for the scrollbar's new thickness, 2) set the scrollbar's thickness.

1. Adjust the ScrollContainer theme to match your desired thickness

   1. In your project FileSystem create a folder under res:// called themes
   2. First, create a `Custom Theme` -- either one applied to your ScrollContainer itself, or some parent node.
   3. Click the + to add a new type
   4. Select ScrollContainer
   5. Click the Style tab (the rainbow + drop icon)
   6. Click the + next to Panel
   7. Click `<Empty>`
   8. Select New StyleBoxFlat
   9. Double-click the StyleBoxFlat so it shows up in the Inspector
   10. In the Inspector:

       1. Open Border Width
       2. Set Right to 55
       3. Click the Save icon and name it `some_scroll_bar_theme` and put it in the `res://themes` folder
   11. Click on your ScrollContainer

       1. Expand its Theme Overrides

          1. Styles

             1. Drag your new `some_scroll_bar_theme` and drop it in the ScrollContainer
2. In the ScrollContainer's Script, create a new script and supply it with either:

#### `C#`

```
using Godot;

public partial class some_scroll_container_script_name : ScrollContainer
{
  public override void _Ready()
  {
    Vector2 size = new Vector2(55, GetVScrollBar().CustomMinimumSize.Y);
    GetVScrollBar().CustomMinimumSize = size;
  }
}
```

#### `Godot`

```
extends ScrollContainer

func _ready():
   get_v_scroll_bar().custom_minimum_size.x = 55;
```

Note: as this adjustment happens at runtime, you won't see the change in your Scene's 2D view.